# How to properly clean up scene on exit?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my scene I have number of child nodes, with or without actions. Using ARC, what kind of cleanups I have to perform in `onExit` method?

Do I have to stop all animated sprites(`stopAllActions`) and then remove from parent(`removeFromParentAndCleanup`) or framework will do that for me?

Any checklist for that?

Comment: If you did cleanup before ARC, it's quite similar. Set strong ivars to nil, which releases them. Properties are the same - self.foo = nil.

Comment: I was more curious about `cocos2D` framework internal cleanups.

Comment: Why would they change?

Comment: because of OpenGL. There might be some states and many other stuff which may require some cleanup.

Comment: i would add to your checklist ... if you registered as a touch delegate, do remove yourself in the onExit method.

Comment: That was helpful. +1. I was stuck on my touches not working on new scene. Turns out they had been swallowed.

Comment: The other one which you have to do is remove observer if you have set notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You cleanup the mess you created. ;)

Any potentially retaining strong references (ie if you have a strong reference to a sibling or parent node). Any memory you malloc'ed. Things like that.

What you don't do is to run any cleanup on cocos2d itself. You don't remove all children, you don't unschedule selectors, you don't stop actions. This is all done by cocos2d.